# Java - Clearing the selection in OTHER JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel, listselectionlistener

I have the following problem:
There are 2 JLists in my frame:

```
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    ownlistModel = new DefaultListModel();
    fillList();


    ownBookList = new JList(ownlistModel);
    ownBookList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    ownBookList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    ownBookList.setSelectedIndex(-1);



    userlist = new JList(listModel);
    userlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    userlist.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    userlist.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Now, these are mutually exclusive, so if someone clicks an item in the one list, the previous selection in the other list should be cleared.

```
  ls2Handler = new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
              if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {


            //  System.out.println(ownBookList.getSelectedValue().toString().length());
                 Global.selectedUser =  ownBookList.getSelectedValue().toString();
                 Global.selectedIndex = ownBookList.getSelectedIndex();
             userlist.clearSelection();
                  updateFields(Global.selectedUser, 1);

              }


        }
    };

        lsHandler = new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                  if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {

                //  System.out.println(userlist.getSelectedValue().toString().length());

                      Global.selectedUser =  userlist.getSelectedValue().toString();
                     Global.selectedIndex = userlist.getSelectedIndex();
                   ownBookList.clearSelection();
                      updateFields(Global.selectedUser, 0);
                  }


            }
            };


        userlist.addListSelectionListener(lsHandler);
        ownBookList.addListSelectionListener(ls2Handler);
```

On calling the Value is adjusting function I always get the nullpointerException:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at Books$3.valueChanged(Books.java:199)     at
>   javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)

Why is that? As you can see, they have been declared and should be accessible.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Robin I figured it out. I wasn't aware that the method clearselection() triggers the listener. 
It's quick and dirty but it works:

```
    ls2Handler = new ListSelectionListener(){
        @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
          if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {

              if (ownBookList.getSelectedValue()!=null) {
                  userlist.clearSelection();
                  Global.selectedUser =  ownBookList.getSelectedValue().toString();
                  Global.selectedIndex = ownBookList.getSelectedIndex();
                  updateFields(Global.selectedUser);
              }

                else {

                    }

          }

    }
};

    lsHandler = new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
              if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {

                  if (userlist.getSelectedValue()!=null) {
                     ownBookList.clearSelection();
                      Global.selectedUser =  userlist.getSelectedValue().toString();
                      Global.selectedIndex = userlist.getSelectedIndex();
                      updateFields(Global.selectedUser);


                  }
                  else {

                  }
              }


        }
        };
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The `getSelectedValue()` method can return `null`, and you are calling `toString()` on that `null` object

```
userlist.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

See the documentation of that method:

> Returns the value for the smallest selected cell index; the selected value when only a single item is selected in the list. When multiple items are selected, it is simply the value for the smallest selected index. Returns null if there is no selection.

And since you clear the selection on list `B` when you select something on list `A`, you will quickly run into this exception.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. I can logically see where the problem is. I am a little confused though because I can't see why it happens here. I am not calling the function for the List that I deselected the item in but the one where the selection is made, so I am not calling the toString method on an unexisting selection...Where am I mistaken? Thanks again!

Comment: @Halest clearing the selection will also fire a `ListSelectionEvent`, hence will trigger the listener.